# RegEx for getting path and filename from code requiring path

Tags: c++, regex

I been searching for the RegEX to extract files with path from code, so that I could check if they exists but ended up not getting exactly what I wanted. This I guess is most likely due to lack of RegEX knowledge.

I got a bit frustrated about every single RegEx example I ran, I always ended up getting filenames of files without Paths, my requirements are fairly simple in sed kinda way.

/"+/{1,6}+.myext"/

I the path needs between 1-6 deep, it needs to be filename with certain extension, the path are unix based but not starting always starting with forward slash. And the filename cannot start with a dot.

Comment: Your regex (which is probably invalid syntax) doesn't look anything like you describe. Why don't you start here: [www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: can you elaborate on "but not starting always starting with forward slash"? Are they always starting with a slash?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in powershell and it works, I'm sure you can use something like this in your app.

```
$Matches = @()
$String = '/this/is/a/long/path/and/Filename.MyExtension'
if ($String -match '^(/?[^/]+){1,6}/([^/.][^/]*[.]MyExtension)$') {
    $Matches[2]
    } # end if
```

yields

```
Filename.MyExtension
```

This works by looking for between 1 and 6 groups of strings each string must start with a / and the string continues through all non slash characters or the character group must not start with a /

The last group of characters must not start with a / or . followed by all the non slash characters upto the required dot extension [in this case "MyExtension']

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is late for the OPs question, but something that will be of help to the OP and to others trying to use RegEx is [regexlib.com](http://www.regexlib.com/); they have a large library of Regular Expressions. They also have a [RegEx tester](http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) which is very helpful in testing your RegEx code. Also [Ultrapico's Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a very useful tool for creating regular expressions.